# How to calculate the different between two datepickers

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

im trying to calculate the date different for a two datepicker in JavaScript.  I tried following other posts, but everytime i calculate the date diff * price, but i'm not getting a result.  Can someone please direct me into the right direction in order to accomplish my goal in finding date differential between two datepickers.

```
    //input/saving data for the next form
$(".next").click(function(){
start = $('#checkin').val();
ends = $('#checkout').val();
diff = (ends - start);
days = diff/1000/60/60/24;

//roomPrice = price inserted into selection type(Single = 65, Double = 100, Suite = 120)
roomPrice = Rprices[selectType.value];

//preparing form5
fields = [$('#FirstName').val() + ' ' + $('#LastName').val(),
$('#phone').val(),
$('#email').val(),
$('#StreetAddress').val(),
$('#City').val(),
$('#state').val(),
$('#zip').val(),
$('#checkin').val(),
$('#checkout').val(),
$('#RoomType').val(),
$('#NumOfPeople').val(),
document.getElementById("total").value = days * roomPrice];
```

Comment: You should cut the code down to just the relative parts

Comment: Are you using the jQuery Datepicker widget?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  Yes, i'm using the JQuery Datepicker widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are asking but:

```
start = $('#checkin').val(); // assuming this is a date
ends = $('#checkout').val(); // assuming this is a date
var start_date = new Date(start); // assuming the format is correct
var end_date = new Date(ends); // assuming the format is correct
var diff_ms = end_date.getTime() - start_date.getTime(); // assuming both dates exist
```

will get you the time difference in milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you!! That solved my problem.  All i did was change end_date.getTime() to end_date.getDate() - .... since i wanted the difference in days not in milliseconds.  Thank you, you made my day.

Answer (score 0):

```
getDateDiff(time1, time2) {
      var t2 = new Date(time1);
      var t1 = new Date(time2);
      var diffMS = t1 - t2;
      var ret = "";
      ret = ret + parseInt(diffMS / 1000 / 60 / 60).toString() + " hours ";
      diffMS = diffMS - parseInt(diffMS / 1000 / 60 / 60) * 60 * 60 * 1000;
      ret = ret + parseInt(diffMS / 1000 / 60).toString() + " min ";
      diffMS = diffMS - parseInt(diffMS / 1000 / 60) * 60 * 1000;
      ret = ret + parseInt(diffMS / 1000).toString() + " sec";
      return ret ;
    }
```